# What can I put in initialization of an inherited class in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, initialization-list, qdjango

I created a Qt class called video like following:

video.h

```
class Video : public QDjangoModel {
    Q_OBJECT
//  ...

public:
    explicit Video(QObject *parent = 0);
//  ...
};
```

video.cpp

```
Video::Video(QObject *parent) : QDjangoModel(parent) {}
```

and following error occured:

```
In file included from ../OnlineVideoPlayer/video.h:7:0,
                 from ../OnlineVideoPlayer/video.cpp:28: ../../../bin/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include/QtCore/qobject.h: In
copy constructor 'QDjangoModel::QDjangoModel(const QDjangoModel&)':
../../../bin/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include/QtCore/qobject.h:333:5:
error: 'QObject::QObject(const QObject&)' is private
/usr/local/include/qdjango/db/QDjangoModel.h:72:22: error: within this
context In file included from ../OnlineVideoPlayer/video.cpp:28:0:
../OnlineVideoPlayer/video.h: In copy constructor 'Video::Video(const
Video&)': ../OnlineVideoPlayer/video.h:14:7: note: synthesized method
'QDjangoModel::QDjangoModel(const QDjangoModel&)' first required here
```

This class extends class named `QDjangoModel` (which is included in [QDjango](https://code.google.com/p/qdjango/)) and `QDjangoModel` extends `QObject`.
When I create class on Qt creator, it creates following template:

```
NewClass::NewClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}
```

and I thought `: QObject(parent)` is parent's constructor, so I replaced it to `: QDjangoModel(parent)` but it seems incorrect.

Questions:

**Q1. What `: QObject(parent)` mean?**

I googled about initialization list, and I understand the meaning of following code:

```
class NewClass {
public:
    FileReader(QString name);
private:
    QString m_name;
};

NewClass::NewClass(QString name) : m_name(name) {}
```

In this case,

```
m_name = name;
```

is executed when constructor executed, right?

But in my case,

```
NewClass::NewClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}
```

or

```
NewClass::NewClass(QObject *parent) : QDjangoModel(parent) {}
```

don't mean

```
QObject = parent;
```

or

```
QDjangoModel = parent;
```

obviously so my understanding for `m_name(name)` case is not applied for `QObject(parent)` case.

**Q2. What can I fix this error?**

Comment: The problem seems to be related with the synthesized copy constructor. What's on `video.cpp:28:0`? Anyway, when you do `: QObject(parent)` in the initializer list, you cause that QObject constructor to be called before your class object is constructed. That's a typical use when you want to call a base class constructor other than the default one.

Comment: video.cpp:28:0 is `#include "video.h"`. So `: QObject(parent)` is like `super();` which is called in the first line of the constructor in Java, right?

Comment: `C++` has multiple inheritance, but that is a similar concept, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide a copy constructor in your code, the compiler synthesizes one for you.

The compiler-synthesized copy constructor calls the base class copy constructor.

It is like it is implemented (well, synthesized `:)` ) this way:

```
Video::Video(const Video&) : QDjangoModel::QDjangoModel(const QDjangoModel&) 
{ /* [...] */ }
```

I think the problem is that the in the call flow starting from the compiler-synthesized copy constructor, there is a call to `QObject::QObject(const QObject&)` which is private.

Qt don't want you to copy `QObject`, so you must not or your code won't compile!

This (i.e., having the copy ctor private) is a typical and good design which is used when an object shouldn't be made copyable.

As a solution, try defining your own copy constructor so that the `QObect` copy constructor doesn't get called.

Example:

```
Video::Video(const Video&) 
{;}
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for late reply. I declared `Video(const Video &video);` in header file and `Video::Video(const Video &) {}` in the code, but following warning occured: "base class 'class QDjangoModel' should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor [-Wextra]" In addition, original constructor had default value for first argument (like `Video(QObject *parent = 0);`) to allow instanciation without argument (like `Video video = new Video()`) but in this case what value should be the default value?